# 可変な長さの対象に対して、予め配列に格納した色をなるべくランダムに指定したい

Tags: php

やりたいこと
可変な長さに対して、予め配列に格納したなるべくランダムな値を付与したい

現状

```
$colorAry = ['blue','yellow','green','black'];
shuffle($colorAry);
foreach ($dataAry as $value) :
  echo $colorAry[$i];
  $i++;
endforeach;
```

$dataAry配列要素数は可変です。
$dataAry配列要素数が、$colorAry配列要素数を上回ることがあるため、事前に
$colorAry = array_merge($colorAry,$colorAry);
と書いたりしていたのですが、$dataAry配列の数が100以上になることもあるため、もう少しスマートに書きたいです。何かよい案はありますか？

Comment: $dateArrayの要素数はわかりますよね。だとしたら、shuffle用に必要な分だけ$colorAryを連結した配列、$colorAry2をつくるしょりはどうでしょうか？

Comment: 「なるべくランダム」というのがあいまいな仕様な印象です。もう少し明確にするべきかと思います。例えば「必ず4色はどこかで使うようにして、あとはランダムにする」とか「4色の偏りはなくしたいので各色の出現回数は±2回以内にする」等ですね。

Comment: @atsushi。なるほど。$dateArrayの要素数に応じた配列をその都度作成するわけですね。事前に作成して共通部品化することしか頭にありませんでした……

Comment: @keitaro_so。やりたいランダムをうまく言語化できないですが、要素数が8の場合は各色2回。要素数が12の場合は各色3回。4色の偏りをなるべくなくしたいです